# How do I prevent AngularFire from synchronizing stale data when coming back online?

Tags: angularjs, firebase, angularfire

I'm using [AngularFire](http://angularfire.com/index.html) to manage synchronizing state between a collaborative single page application and FireBase. This works exceptionally well when all clients are online, but I've found that when one returns from sleep and reconnects, it's stale view of the world seems to overwrite the more up-to-date data on the other clients.

### Observations

In my app, students are considered checked-in if they have the `checkInTime` property set to a value, and checked-out otherwise. When one client goes offline with the example data below and another still active client checks-out the third student, the student may re-appear when the offline client comes back online (there seems to be a period of instability at this point where all clients' data shuffles a bit, which I understand is a natural part of FireBase's merge process).

### Implementation Details

Specifically, I have data in this form:

```
{
  "users" : [ null, {
    "center" : {
      "students" : [ {
        "checkOutTime" : "2013-09-10T02:32:15.916Z",
        "last" : "Adams",
        "dob" : "10/09/03",
        "visible" : true,
        "first" : "Bob"
      }, {
        "checkOutTime" : "2013-09-10T16:22:33.591Z",
        "last" : "Adams",
        "dob" : "11/28/08",
        "visible" : true,
        "first" : "George"
      }, {
        "last" : "Smith",
        "dob" : "01/08/03",
        "checkInTime" : "2013-09-11T02:59:35.988Z",
        "visible" : true,
        "first" : "Sam"
      }
   ]
}
```

This data is bound to my `$rootScope` via `angularFire(new Firebase(centerUri + 'students'), $rootScope, "user.students");` inside an Angular service so that the data can be shared between different views in my app. The `$rootScope.user` object is then bound into child scopes so that my view templates can reference the `students` array.

Also, in my primary view template I display the duration of time a student has been checked in by calling a controller function like this `$scope.getDuration = function (student) { ... }`. Because of this, my primary view also has a setTimeout loop that kicks off a `$scope.$digest()` every 30 seconds to ensure the duration strings are up-to-date.

What I'd like to learn is what I can do to help ensure the correct, newest data wins in the merge process when a client comes back online and what I may be doing wrong to confuse FireBase.

Thanks!

Comment: This has been [logged as an issue](https://github.com/firebase/angularFire/issues/120) within AngularFire on GitHub. Once this has been fixed, I'll add the fixing version as an answer here.

Comment: Is this question still relevant? IIRC, this problem has been solved in the latest releases.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The newer versions of AngularFire use a different synchronization mechanism that does not suffer from this problem, so I'm going to say this issue has been resolved.

The new base API for synchronizing state in AngularFire works similarly to the former angularFireCollection, which I employed for my students array to circumvent this issue. The first version of AngularFire (which I was using above) was synchronizing the entire students array each time any value of any student was changed, causing significant latency and prolific collisions between stale values updated by recently-awoken systems and others making changes against up-to-date data. Updating each student individually as it changes effectively eliminated the period of instability in my application and allowed much more graceful catch-up process as stale systems re-sync.